# Are External Activities like Template Building Blocks?

Tags: workflow

I understand one of the ideas behind External Activities for workflow in SDL Tridion 2013 was to allow the same approach to CM-side development.

This includes:

- Visual Studio IDE for development
- Debugging
- Same TCMUpload to place the code on the CMS

Are TCM urls also managed? For example, does it matter if we reference something like this:

`AssemblyTbbId = "tcm:5-555-2048"`

Or should we use WebDAV urls? **In other words, is it safe to content port External Activities?**

*And do External Activities have others things in common with TBBs worth knowing?*

Comment: Some thing the external activity does not have in common with TBB is that the external activity only gets access to CM though a core service clIent. There is not a full Tom API available.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use WebDAV URLs and probably should if porting process definitions between environments is important to you (i.e. the TCM IDs of your Template Building Blocks could change).

You reference them in an external activity "script" as:

```
AssemblyTbbId = "/webdav/200%20Website/Building%20Blocks/Path/To/Your/Assembly.tbbasm"
Type = "YourNameSpace.YourClassName"
```

See [Rob Stevenson-Leggett's](https://tridion.stackexchange.com/users/43/rob-stevenson-leggett) [Gist](https://gist.github.com/rsleggett/5214230#file-wireup-cs) and [associated blog post](http://www.building-blocks.com/thinking/sdl-tridion-2013-preview/) for a more comprehensive example.

Comment: To add to this, tcm uris are only managed in Dreamweaver templates and probably some other plain text tabs. external activities are uploaded like a C# TBB and uris in C# TBBs are not managed either.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I didn't /think/ they were managed but didn't want to write as such until I'd had a chance to test